# preg_split to get ending number from string

Tags: preg-split

```
$str = "check-me-01";
if(preg_match("#(\d){0,}$#",$str)) {
    $strArr = preg_split("#(\d){0,}$#",$str,2);
    print_r($strArr);
}
```

I am using above script to get 01 from the string that can be any number.
but I always get

> Array ( [0] => check-me- [1] => )

anybody can help me with this?

Comment: why the `{0,}` ? Why not `{1,}`? What if the string would be check-me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get 01 from that string, you should be using just [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), not preg_split.  Visit that link, and examine how you can obtain the resulting matches.

Quote:

> int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )

Note `&$matches`.  That's what you want to look at more closely.

preg_split will consume whatever it matches as the delimiter: that is the problem you are facing.  Thus, whatever is matches will not be in the resulting array--only whatever is on either side.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just forgot that $matches thing. thanks dude.

Comment: Glad to help!  I always forget how to use it, so I look it up each time.  That's why I remembered it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
I also used [POSIX  brackets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

---

### PHP

```
$str = "check-me-01";
if (preg_match("#[[:digit:]]$#",$str)) {
    // the regex matches a zero length string, so just the position when it is true
    // the (?=regex) triggers a positive lookahead
    // it is true in this case, if you have many digits at the end of the string
    $strArr = preg_split("#(?=[[:digit:]]+$)#",$str,2);
    print_r($strArr);
}
```